# scale conversion for a data set in r

Tags: r

is1

```
0
0.06
-0.58
-0.87
-1
-0.77
-1
-0.62
0.83
-0.86
-0.83
0.42
-0.6
1
0.47
0.94
0.23
0.46
-0.98
-0.04
-0.39
0.99
0.81
0.11
-0.85
-0.56
0.14
1
-0.79
-0.06
-0.58
0.79
0.71
-0.2
0.69
-0.33
0.64
-0.76
0.14
-0.41
1
-0.83
0.01
-0.86
-0.65
-0.58
0.5
-0.39
-0.8
-0.36
0.17
-0.96
-0.46
-0.78
```

My data set looks like this, now how do I convert the scale to 0.1 to 1?

Comment: @akrun: I didn't get you?. It ranges from - 1 to +1

Comment: You have `rescale` in `plotrix` package. Also http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
is1 <- c(0, 0.06, -0.58, -0.87, -1, -0.77, -1, -0.62, 0.83, -0.86, -0.83, 
         0.42, -0.6, 1, 0.47, 0.94, 0.23, 0.46, -0.98, -0.04, -0.39, 
         0.99, 0.81, 0.11, -0.85, -0.56, 0.14, 1, -0.79, -0.06, -0.58, 
         0.79, 0.71, -0.2, 0.69, -0.33, 0.64, -0.76, 0.14, -0.41, 1, 
        -0.83, 0.01, -0.86, -0.65, -0.58, 0.5, -0.39, -0.8, -0.36, 0.17, 
        -0.96, -0.46, -0.78)

nmin <- 0.1
nmax <- 1
```

Using the `rescale` function from the `plotrix` package:

```
library(plotrix)
res1 <- rescale(is1, c(nmin, nmax))
head(res1)
# [1] 0.5500 0.5770 0.2890 0.1585 0.1000 0.2035
range(res1)
# [1] 0.1 1.0
```

Or from this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25897):

```
res2 <- (nmax-nmin)/(max(is1)-min(is1)) * (is1-min(is1)) + nmin
head(res2)
# [1] 0.5500 0.5770 0.2890 0.1585 0.1000 0.2035
range(res2)
# [1] 0.1 1.0
```